# How to consume and parse xml soap Web Service in Windows Phone application

Tags: c#, web-services

I am new in Windows Phone application and developing my first app. I got stuck in `Web Service`.

The web service that I have is `ws.clearwintech.com/arvind.asmx`

Now from here i want to extract the data from a few web methods like `getarvindNews`, `getarvindAbout` and so on. On clicking a `Button` in one page i want the data to be shown from the web service in the next page.

Till now what i did was i added a service reference to my project where i gave the link of my web service which is given above. Now how do i access a particular web method and perform all the required parsing to get the data? I am using Visual Studio 2010 and C#.

I am also giving my codes:

```
namespace KejriwalPhoneApp
{
    public partial class News : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public News()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void getData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            KejriwalService.arvindSoapClient client = new KejriwalService.arvindSoapClient();

            client.getarvindNewsCompleted += new EventHandler<KejriwalService.getarvindNewsCompletedEventArgs>(client_getarvindNewsCompleted);
            client.getarvindNewsAsync();
        }

        void client_getarvindNewsCompleted(object sender, KejriwalService.getarvindNewsCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBlock1.Text = e.Result.ToString();
            // throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Please help me with codes to extract data from just one web method and display that data on a click of a `Button` in one page and the result should be shown in another page of my application..

The output that i am getting is KejriwalPhoneApp.KejriwalService.arvindSoapClient. I want the data from the web service

My Web Service Code

public arvind()
    {

```
    //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
    //InitializeComponent(); 
}

[WebMethod]
public DataSet getarvindDeviceId()
{
    string strSQL;
    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
    strSQL = "select * from tbl_DeviceIdAndroid;";
    //strSQL = "delete from tbl_DeviceIdIphone;";
    myDataSet = ExecuteDataset(strSQL);

    return myDataSet;
}

[WebMethod]
public DataSet getarvindAndroid()
{
    string strSQL;
    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
    strSQL = "select * from tbl_DeviceIdAndroid;";
    //strSQL = "delete from tbl_DeviceIdIphone;";
    myDataSet = ExecuteDataset(strSQL);

    return myDataSet;
}

[WebMethod]
public DataSet getarvindIphone()
{
    string strSQL;
    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
    strSQL = "select id,status,Event_Name from tbl_event;";
    //strSQL = "delete from tbl_DeviceIdIphone;";
    myDataSet = ExecuteDataset(strSQL);

    return myDataSet;
}


[WebMethod]
public DataSet getarvindMedia()
{
    string strSQL;
    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
    strSQL = "select * from tbl_videos order by id desc;";
    myDataSet = ExecuteDataset(strSQL);

    return myDataSet;
}

[WebMethod]
public DataSet getarvindData()
{
    string strSQL;
    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
    strSQL = "select landing_page,news_icon, event_icon,  donation_icon , about_icon  from tbl_adv_images;";
    myDataSet = ExecuteDataset(strSQL);

    return myDataSet;
}

// Kamakhya 
[WebMethod]
public DataSet getarvindEvents()
{
    string strSQL;
    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
    strSQL = "SELECT Event_Name,Event_Description,Time_Zone,uTime,Location,Event_Date,image_path from tbl_Event  where Event_Format_Date>UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-28800 order by  Event_Format_Date asc;";
    myDataSet = ExecuteDataset(strSQL);

    return myDataSet;
}

[WebMethod]
public DataSet getarvindNews()
{
    string strSQL;
    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
    strSQL = "SELECT id, News_Title , News_Description , Date_Start , image_path from tbl_News order by id desc ;";
    myDataSet = ExecuteDataset(strSQL);

    return myDataSet;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are already consuming the service. What is your exact problem?

Comment: Maybe the web service isn't _sending_ any data? Have you tried it with a simpler scenario, like a console application? Maybe try a non-async version in a console app just to see if the service works at all.

Comment: I didn't ask about those. I'm asking about a .NET application. Maybe there's something wrong with .NET? Or maybe there's something wrong with your understanding of how to consume the service on .NET?

Comment: Sorry, no, you aren't paying me enough for codes.

Comment: @bhaskar07 What type of web service you are using ? Is it `WCF` or `PHP`

Comment: @Ajay I am using asp.net web service

Comment: @bhaskar07 Can you post web service code?

Comment: @Ajay Please check the code i have posted

Comment: @Ajay I want to extract data from the web method getarvindNews

Answer (score 1):

It seems your already on right path. In Client_GetArvindNewsCompleted() asynch method callback, your getting the result with all the news your looking for. So now point is instead of showing this on same page, you need to show it on next page right? for that instead of storing the result in current page textblock text, store it in current user session from this callback redirect user to next page and from there get the data from temporary user session, you can cleanup the user session here immediately to free up the memory.

Comment: thanks i will try and let u know. ya i am trying to display it in a new page.

Comment: the output that i am getting is KejriwalPhoneApp.KejriwalService.arvindSoapClient...Please help if you can

Answer (score 0):

You are returning **DataSet** from web service and you are converting it to string in `client_getarvindNewsCompleted`. You can not use DataSet in Windows Phone apps.

```
void client_getarvindNewsCompleted(object sender, KejriwalService.getarvindNewsCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
       var data = e.Result;
        // throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: for dataset which using statemnt should i use?

Comment: You can not use DataSet. you need to try other way to get the data.
You need to modify your web method.